# Symfony 3 - expected argument of type array given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have found all subjects on google and did not get the solution.

I have this error:

> Expected argument of type "PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\Module",
> "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given

I want to select multiple Modules in the list but when I click on save I have the error.

My Form:

```
<?php

namespace PL\AppAccueilBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class AppAccueilModuleType extends AbstractType {
private $idCompany;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $this->idCompany = $options['idCompany'];

    $builder
        ->add('company', CollectionType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PLUserBundle:Company',
            'choice_label' => 'Name',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->remove('company')
        ->add('module', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PLPlatformBundle:Module',
            'choice_label' => function ($allChoices) {
                if ($allChoices->getRef() != null)
                    return $allChoices->getRef() . ' - ' .   $allChoices->getTitre() . " (" . $allChoices->getSupport()->getTitre() . ")";
                else
                    return $allChoices->getTitre() . " (" . $allChoices->getSupport()->getTitre() . ")";
            },
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->getModulesListForCompany($this->idCompany);
            },
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'PL\AppAccueilBundle\Entity\AppAccueilModule',
        'idCompany' => null
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return 'pl_appaccueilbundle_appaccueilmodule';
}
}
```

My Entity:

```
<?php

namespace PL\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PL\AppAccueilBundle\Entity\ParcoursModule;
use PL\AppChallengeBundle\Entity\ChallengeModule;
use PL\UserBundle\Entity\Company;
use PL\UserBundle\Entity\Logo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* Module
* @ORM\Table(name="pl_module")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PL\PlatformBundle\Repositor\ModuleRepository")
*/
class Module {
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $titre;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="ref", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $ref;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\Support")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $support;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\Theme")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $theme;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PL\UserBundle\Entity\Company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $company;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PL\UserBundle\Entity\Logo", cascade="persist")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pl_logo")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $logo;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\Document", cascade="persist")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pl_module_document")
 */
private $documents;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\ChasseZone", cascade="persist")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pl_module_chasse_zone")
 */
private $chasseZone;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\Question", cascade="persist")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pl_module_quiz")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 */
private $question;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="code_iframe", type="string", length=4095, nullable=true)
 */
private $codeIframe;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\ChasseImage", cascade="persist")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pl_module_chasse_image")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $chasseImage;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PL\AppAccueilBundle\Entity\ParcoursModule", mappedBy="module", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
 */
private $parcours;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PL\AppChallengeBundle\Entity\ChallengeModule", mappedBy="module", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
 */
private $challenges;



/**
 * Get id
 * @return int
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titre
 * @param string $titre
 * @return module
 */
public function setTitre($titre) {
    $this->titre = $titre;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titre
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitre() {
    return $this->titre;
}

/**
 * Set ref
 * @param string $ref
 * @return module
 */
public function setRef($ref) {
    $this->ref = $ref;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ref
 * @return string
 */
public function getRef() {
    return $this->ref;
}

/**
 * Set support
 * @param Support $support
 * @return Module
 */
public function setSupport(Support $support) {
    $this->support = $support;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get support
 * @return Support
 */
public function getSupport() {
    return $this->support;
}

/**
 * Set theme
 * @param Theme $theme
 * @return Module
 */
public function setTheme(Theme $theme) {
    $this->theme = $theme;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get theme
 * @return Theme
 */
public function getTheme() {
    return $this->theme;
}

/**
 * Set company
 *
 * @param Company $company
 * @return Module
 */
public function setCompany(Company $company) {
    $this->company = $company;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get company
 * @return Company
 */
public function getCompany() {
    return $this->company;
}

/**
 * Set logo
 * @param Logo $logo
 * @return Module
 */
public function setLogo(Logo $logo = null) {
    $this->logo = $logo;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get logo
 * @return Logo
 */
public function getLogo() {
    return $this->logo;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->chasseZone = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->question = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->parcours = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->challenges = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add document
 * @param Document $document
 * @return Module
 */
public function addDocument(Document $document) {
    $this->documents[] = $document;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove document
 * @param Document $document
 */
public function removeDocument(Document $document) {
    $this->documents->removeElement($document);
}

/**
 * Get documents
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getDocuments() {
    return $this->documents;
}

/**
 * Set codeIframe
 * @param string $codeIframe
 * @return Module
 */
public function setCodeIframe($codeIframe) {
    $this->codeIframe = $codeIframe;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get codeIframe
 * @return string
 */
public function getCodeIframe() {
    return $this->codeIframe;
}

/**
 * Set chasseImage
 * @param ChasseImage $chasseImage
 * @return Module
 */
public function setChasseImage(ChasseImage $chasseImage = null) {
    $this->chasseImage = $chasseImage;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get chasseImage
 * @return ChasseImage
 */
public function getChasseImage() {
    return $this->chasseImage;
}

/**
 * Remove chasseZone
 * @param ChasseZone $ch
 */
public function removeChasseZone(ChasseZone $ch) {
    $this->chasseZone->removeElement($ch);
}

/**
 * Get chasseZone
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getChasseZone() {
    return $this->chasseZone;
}

/**
 * Add chasseZone
 * @param \PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\ChasseZone $chasseZone
 * @return Module
 */
public function addChasseZone(ChasseZone $chasseZone) {
    $this->chasseZone[] = $chasseZone;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get questions
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getQuestions() {
    return $this->question;
}

/**
 * Add question
 * @param \PL\PlatformBundle\Entity\Question $question
 * @return Module
 */
public function addQuestion(Question $question) {
    $this->question[] = $question;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove question
 * @param Question $question
 */
public function removeQuestion(Question $question) {
    $this->question->removeElement($question);
}

/**
 * Get parcours
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getParcours() {
    return $this->parcours;
}

/**
 * Add parcours
 * @param ParcoursModule $parcours
 * @return Module
 */
public function addParcours(ParcoursModule $parcours) {
    $this->parcours[] = $parcours;
    $parcours->setModule($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove parcours
 * @param ParcoursModule $parcours
 */
public function removeParcours(ParcoursModule $parcours) {
    $this->parcours->removeElement($parcours);
}

/**
 * Get Challenges
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getChallenges() {
    return $this->challenges;
}

/**
 * Add challenge module
 * @param ChallengeModule $challenge
 * @return Module
 */
public function addChallenge(ChallengeModule $challenge) {
    $this->challenges[] = $challenge;
    $challenge->setModule($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove challenges module
 * @param ChallengeModule $challenge
 */
public function removeChallenges(ChallengeModule $challenge) {
    $this->challenges->removeElement($challenge);
}
}
```

Thinks

Comment: if you need multiple modules then you can use CollectionType Field.http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Add also "PL\AppAccueilBundle\Entity\AppAccueilModule" code.